# Event if I press button x times

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS / HTML code. It is supposed to give you an input. When you click the button as many times as you wrote in the input then it the screen is supposed to say 'stop' but that's not happening and idk why. How can I fix this?

```js
var text2
let count = 1;
var correct = 1;

function check() {
  text2 = document.getElementById('questions').value;
  correct = correct + 1;
  count = count + 1;

  if (count === text2) {
    var score = "stop";
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = score;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>how many?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
<button onclick="check()" id='but'>ok</button>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Comment: `text2` is probably a string. You can remedy this by changing `text2` in the if statement to `+text2` (convert to integer). It might also work if you change `===` to `==`.

Comment: in your check() function, output the variables you are comparing. Are they reaching the expected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>how many?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
    <button onclick="check()" id='div'>ok</button>
    <div id='div'> </div>
    <script>
      var count = 0;
      function check() {
        let user_input = document.getElementById('questions').value;
        if (++count === parseInt(user_input)) {
          document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "stop";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `===` to compare, which checks type before comparing. `count` is an integer and `text2` is a String, so it will always return `false`. Instead, first parse `text2` into an integer, then compare like so:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>how many?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
  <button onclick="check()" id='but'> ok </button>
  <div id='div'> </div>

  <script>
    var text2
    let count = 0;
    var correct = 0;

    function check() {
      text2 = document.getElementById('questions').value;
      correct = correct + 1;
      count++;
      if (count === parseInt(text2)) {
        var score = "stop";
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = score;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or instead use `==` which only checks for value:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>how many?<input type="text" id="questions"></p>
  <button onclick="check()" id='but'> ok </button>
  <div id='div'> </div>

  <script>
    var text2
    let count = 0;
    var correct = 1;

    function check() {
      text2 = document.getElementById('questions').value;
      correct = correct + 1;
      count++;
      if (count == text2) {
        var score = "stop";
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = score;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @pavel OP wanted it to start at 1.

Comment: Correct answer is above from @Nenad. The OP: _When you click the button as many times as you wrote..._ - when I write '2', 'stop' should be displayed after 2nd click (not after 1st one).

Comment: @pavel I've changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This shoud do the trick:

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>how many?<input type="text" onInput="onInput()" id="questions"></p>
<button onclick="check()" id = 'but'> ok </button>
<div id = 'div'> </div>

  <script>
    var text2;
    let count = 0

    function onInput() {
      var element = document.getElementById('questions');
      //replace window 
      text2 = element.value;
    }

    function check(){
      count = count + 1;
      console.log(count);
      if (count === parseInt(text2)){
        var score = "stop";
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = score;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```